# Inserted before the newly created child node is invalid?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="wb" type="text" />
    <input id="an" type="button" value="按钮" />
    <ul id="ul1">

    </ul>
    <script>
        window.onload=function()
        {
            var oWb = document.getElementById("wb");
            var btn = document.getElementById("an");
            var oUl = document.getElementById("ul1");
            btn.onclick=function()
            {
                var oLi = document.createElement("li");

                oLi.innerHTML = oWb.value;
                oUl.insertBefore(oLi,oLi[0]);   

            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to insert each click, are inserted in front of a li, then oUl.insertBefore (oLi, oLi [0]); choose to insert in oLi [0] why not die? Is not every click to create a li, and then insert the first 0 in this index, it should be no problem?

Comment: `oLi` is the list item you just created. There is no reason why trying to access `oLi[0]` would make any sense here. If you just want to refer to the first child of the list - then just do that, `oUl.firstChild`

Comment: @CBroe Could you please translate what he asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand [how `insertBefore` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). Your `oLi` element doesn't even have a `[0]` property. Instead, you will want to pass `oUl.firstChild` to get the `oLi` inserted at the front.

```
oUl.insertBefore(oLi, oUl.firstChild);
```

Comment: I see there is a way to add a var aLi = oUl.getElementsByTagName ("li") to index the notification where to insert, then ask if it is not necessary to create getElementsByTagName i can use this tag's index？

Comment: Yes, you could also use [`oUl.childNodes[index]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
 or [`oUl.children[index]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)